# Android: Location: Is the returned altitude value measured from inside the building includes the sea level height to building?

Tags: android, geolocation

I found this link [Google Maps Find Altitude](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm)

from there, you may receive this kind of result (sample result):

> number,latitude,longitude,meters,feet
>
> 0,35.612557,139.62865699999998,17.025,55.857

Problems:

1. I am wondering if the 17.025m altitude value includes the sea level
   height.
2. Is it the returned altitude value measured from sea level

**UPDATE:**
additional problem: What will be the returned value for altitude inside the building's basement floor if the floor is under the sea level?

Answer (score 1):

See level height is considered to be 0, and any other altitude, this include building too, are positive values, and oceans floor and depths are negative values. For more details you can read this:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/

Comment: May I ask your opinion on this follow-up question. What will be the returned value for altitude in the building's basement floor if the basement is under sea level?

Comment: You should get the right value (negative one), but at this rate it depends on provider and sensitivity :)